# MongoDB: Fastest way to index by two fields?

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing, nosql

I'm using MongoDB as a database for a game server network.  Every player on the network has two means by which to identify them: their username, and their UUID.  Both fields are unique to each player, and it is often useful to retrieve a player's UUID given their name, retrieve their name given their UUID, and retrieve the entire document given either their name or their UUID.  Without regard for space requirements, which indexing scheme would allow for these queries to operate the fastest?

My idea is to create a unique index for each of the two fields, but I'm curious if MongoDB offers any better optimizations, especially when I only want to retrieve one field given the other.  I've read that compound indexes can allow for covered queries, where the full document need not be retrieved, but I'm not sure if this could degrade performance compared to having one index for each field.

Comment: Keep reading at least up to the part on [Index Prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes) which will tell you why a compound index with "both" does not work for "either/or" selection ( unless you create two indexes with the field order reversed on one of them). Using an `$or` as is implied for "either field" does however allow multiple indexes to be used as per your "idea". Not sure if that is what you are getting at, but it sounds like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance is always down to what the bottleneck is (whether it's Disk I/O, Network, CPU or RAM) but if your player documents are very large, two compound indexes would help: **[UUID,username]** and **[username,UUID]**. The first one will be the most efficient way to retrieve the username given the UUID, and the latter will help retrieve the UUID given the username.

In practice though, I think unique indexes on just [username] and [UUID] would be almost as fast.